Text beside horizontal line
This question is similar to this one. I also want to write some text beside horizontal lines. The difference is that the content of the cells are commutative diagrams. The solution provided by David Carlisle actually can solve my problem. But in my case is very inefficient because I have to add manually some measurements:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}{f} \& B
  \end{tikzcd}
  \smash{\raisebox{-6pt}{\rlap{\qquad\qquad justification}}}\\
  \hline
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}\ar{d} \& B\ar{d}\\
    C\ar{r} \& D
  \end{tikzcd}
  \smash{\raisebox{-26pt}{\rlap{\qquad\qquad another justification}}}\\
  \hline
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}\ar{dr} \&[4em] B\ar{d}\\
    \& C
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


I have tried with NiceTabular from nicematrix:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c}
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}{f} \& B
  \end{tikzcd}\\
  \Hline
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}\ar{d} \& B\ar{d}\\
    C\ar{r} \& D
  \end{tikzcd}\\
  \Hline
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}\ar{dr} \&[4em] B\ar{d}\\
    \& C
  \end{tikzcd}
  \CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (2-|2) {justification};
    \node at (3-|2) {another justification};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}

but the text overlaps the horizontal lines and the justifications are not aligned. I also tried with bussproofs
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{
  $\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r} \& B
  \end{tikzcd}$
}
\RightLabel{justification}
\UnaryInfC{
  $\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}\ar{d} \& B\ar{d}\\
    C\ar{r} \& D
  \end{tikzcd}$
}
\RightLabel{another justification}
\UnaryInfC{
  $\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}\ar{dr} \&[4em] B\ar{d}\\
    \& C
  \end{tikzcd}$
}
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}

but in this case the horizontal lines have different lengths and the justifications are not aligned.
Is there a way to obtain the result of the image above without have to manually add measurements to raisebox? (Horizontal spacing between the line and the text could also be a problem)

Well, David's answer also relies on manual adjustments, but I take it there's more variation in yours so they're more irritating? Yes, I don't think natural deduction usually features diagrams, so I'm not sure bussproofs is really designed for this. There are newer packages than bussproofs but they are designed to typeset natural deduction proofs, too. (Well, one form of natural deduction to be precise.)

Thanks to everyone for taking the time to solve my problem. All the solutions meet my needs (+1 to everyone). Now I will have a hard time deciding which solution mark as "the" answer.

Similar to what cfr commented in a typesetting world you can and need to do some adjustments. Here's a way to automate most of it. Keys:

"free" the tikzcd environments from tables etc.
replace the hrule with raised text by some inline \tikz{} code
put the tikzcd environments inside a makebox
chose width of makebox AND length of line drawn to be the same length
together this provides the centering wrt to the horizintal line

For further refactoring of this code you could:

replace the value 5 in 5cm and +(5,0) by a constant (\def or \newcommand)
put \tikz{\draw (0,0) -- +(5,0) node[anchor=west,xshift=5mm]{#1};} inside a \newcommand taking 1 parameter, your text
add text width to the node for auto break of text, see pgfmanual


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

  \makebox[5cm]{\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}{f} \& B
  \end{tikzcd}}
  
  \tikz{\draw (0,0) -- +(5,0) node[anchor=west,xshift=5mm]{put some text here};}

  \makebox[5cm]{\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}\ar{d} \& B\ar{d}\\
    C\ar{r} \& D
  \end{tikzcd}}

  \tikz{\draw (0,0) -- +(5,0) node[anchor=west,xshift=5mm]{put some other text here};}

  \makebox[5cm]{\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}\ar{dr} \&[4em] B\ar{d}\\
    \& C
  \end{tikzcd}}

\end{document}


You don't need ampersand replacement. That's one of the advantages of pulling it out of the tabular. At least, that was one of the things I liked about the idea.

Right, thanls for the hint. Just copy&waste ;-)

Thanks so much for all your images, by the way! Really very good of you.

My pleasure @cfr. Hope you can be op again soon.

With tabularray:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
A first example:
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={X[c]X},
  row{1}={belowsep=0pt},
  row{2-Y}={rowsep=0pt},
  row{Z}={abovesep=0pt},
  }
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}{f} \& B
  \end{tikzcd} &\\
  &\SetCell[r=2]{l} justification\\\cline{1-1}
  &\\
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}\ar{d} \& B\ar{d}\\
    C\ar{r} \& D
  \end{tikzcd} &\\
  &\SetCell[r=2]{l} another justification\\\cline{1-1}
  &\\
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}\ar{dr} \&[4em] B\ar{d}\\
    \& C
  \end{tikzcd}\\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
Another example:
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={cl},
  row{1}={belowsep=0pt},
  row{2-Y}={rowsep=0pt},
  row{Z}={abovesep=0pt},
  }
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}{f} \& B
  \end{tikzcd} &\\
  &\SetCell[r=2]{l} justification\\\cline{1-1}
  &\\
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}\ar{d} \& B\ar{d}\\
    C\ar{r} \& D
  \end{tikzcd} &\\
  &\SetCell[r=2]{l} another justification\\\cline{1-1}
  &\\
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}\ar{dr} \&[4em] B\ar{d}\\
    \& C
  \end{tikzcd}\\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}

The trick is creating 2 empty rows with a multirow description.
If you don't like the row separation or the column width I used, they are highly customizable.


Note that this answer uses the fact that tikzcd is a wrapper around a tikzpicture and that you can give arbitrary pgf/tikz keys in the optional argument. In particular, you can use execute at end picture={<code>} to draw arbitrary things at the end of the picture. Moreover, if you use remember picture, you can use nodes constructed at the end of one picture as reference points in the next one.
The upshot of this is that TikZ fits your diagrams into a box and finds the places to draw the lines and put the labels. Using overlay, the labels take no space, so the diagrams remain centred. You also don't need ampersand replacement because there's no tabular here.
The only length set explicitly is the distance of the justifications from the lines. That can't be calculated automatically because it is simply a matter of taste (and space).
The solution defines two styles.

tikz fit=<name> is used to name your tikzcd diagram. It constructs a node around the diagram and names it to your liking.
tikz postscript={<list of named nodes in parentheses>}{<comma-separated list of triples>} where <list of named nodes in parentheses> should typically be the names you gave your diagrams using tikz fit and <comma-separated list of triples> should be a comma-separate list of triples each of which should be of the form <name of upper node>/<name of lower node>/<justification>. Note that the first argument requires parentheses around the node names, whereas the second requires their absence.

For example, you might use tikz fit=pica and tikz fit=picb for two diagrams. You'd then add to the second tikz postscript={(pica) (picb)}{pica/picb/because reason} as illustrated (non-pictorially) below:
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714837/ addaswyd o gwestiwn Luis Turcio: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/714830/ 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc}
\tikzset{%
  tikzcd fit/.style={remember picture,execute at end picture={\node (pic#1) [fit=(current bounding box),remember picture]{};}},
  tikzcd postscript/.style 2 args={execute at end picture={%
      \begin{scope} [overlay]
        \node (a) [fit=#1,inner sep=0pt] {} ;
        \foreach [expand list=true] \i/\j/\k in {#2}
        \draw (a.west |- {$(\i.south)!1/2!(\j.north)$}) coordinate (b) -- (b -| a.east) ++(10pt,0pt) node [anchor=west] {\k};        
      \end{scope}%
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}[tikzcd fit=a]
      A\ar{r}{f} & B 
    \end{tikzcd}

  \begin{tikzcd}[tikzcd fit = b]
    A\ar{r}\ar{d} & B\ar{d}\\
    C\ar{r} & D
  \end{tikzcd}

  \begin{tikzcd}[tikzcd fit = c,tikzcd postscript={(pica) (picb) (picc)}{pica/picb/justification,picb/picc/another justification}]
    A\ar{r}\ar{dr} &[4em] B\ar{d}\\
    & C
  \end{tikzcd}
  
\end{center}

\end{document}

Apologies for the lack of the pictorial bit. Okular has a bug, so you need a certain degree of imagination to read my posts at the moment.
From community:


With nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c}[cell-space-limits=2mm]
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}{f} \& B
  \end{tikzcd}\\
  \Hline
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}\ar{d} \& B\ar{d}\\
    C\ar{r} \& D
  \end{tikzcd}\\
  \Hline
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A\ar{r}\ar{dr} \&[4em] B\ar{d}\\
    \& C
  \end{tikzcd}
  \CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (2-|2) [right] {justification};
    \node at (3-|2) [right] {another justification};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


